Snapchat Publisher Analytics API response
I have a requirement of getting our organisation Snapchat accounts Analytics using Story Studio Analytics API ,I am using PHP client library.
I can able to get the response through API but values are not matching with Snapchat Dashboard values.
Sample API request : https://api.snapkit.com/v1/stories/studio/analytics/publisher/39aed764-32fc-4671-85ac-1fe1cc7cd18e/summary?fromDate=2024-06-01&toDate=2024-06-02
Response:
{
"uniqueViewers": 390,
"avgTimeSpentPerUser": 32.51738,
"totalTimeViewed": 12714,
"uniqueSnapsPerUser": 1.3146478,
"uniqueSnapViews": 523
}
But response is not matching with Story Studio Dashboard.
[
curl -X GET "https://api.snapkit.com/v1/stories/studio/analytics/publisher/39aed764-32fc-4671-85ac-1fe1cc7cd18e/summary?fromDate=2024-06-01&toDate=2024-06-02" -H "accept: application/json" -H "authorization: Bearer Accesstoken"
Clarification needed:

API suggest to pass YYYY-MM-DD (PST time) ,But how to implementing this with API?

